# crontab sends net rpc shutdown but nothing happens

Tags: cron, freebsd, shutdown

I've created two scripts to automate turning on and off computers in my classroom.

Both scripts get a list of MAC ID's and use them to 1)wake up computers (wake command) and 2)shut down computers (net rpc shutdown).

Server is FREEBSD and workstations are win7.

Both scripts look alike except for the part "wake" and "net rpc shutdown". Both scripts work perfectly when runned manually (via shell).

Only WOL script runs with crontab, shutdown script run as-well, but nothing happens to computers.

Cron logs just show, that the script is processed, but computers won't react.

Shutdown script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
#[ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 filename"; exit 1; } #muutujad sätitud?
list="/usr/local/etc/isc-dhcp_192.168.4"
erand="/root/skriptid/WOL/erand.txt"
# kontrollime, kas erandid ja list olemas
[ ! -f $list ] && { echo "EXIT! List puudu asukohas: $list"; exit 1; }
[ ! -f $erand ] && { echo "EXIT! Erandid puudu asukohas: $erand"; exit 1; }
#jätkame
while read line
do
        IFS=' ' read -a array <<< "$line"
        mac=`echo ${array[5]}|sed 's/;//'`
        ip=`echo ${array[7]}|sed 's/;//'`
        host=`echo ${array[1]}`
        if grep -Fq "$ip" $erand
        then
                echo -e "Jatan vahele: HOST: $host IP: $ip MAC: $mac \n----" #exceptions
                sleep 1
        else
                echo -e "Lülitan välja: HOST: $host IP: $ip MAC: $mac \n----"
                net rpc SHUTDOWN -t 15 -f -C "Arvuti lulitub valja. Serveripoolne kask."     -W luunja -U $host\\xx%xx -S $ip
                sleep 1
        fi
done < $list
```

Cron job:

```
40      19      *       *       *     root    /root/skriptid/WOL/shutdown.sh
```

Both script are run by root and have 666 rights.

Is there a way to see cronjob's output besides log?
Is there a known conflict between cronjob and net rpc?

Any help would be appreaciated!'
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate the binary executing the script.

From

```
40 19 * * * root /root/skriptid/WOL/shutdown.sh
```

to

```
40 19 * * * root /bin/sh /root/skriptid/WOL/shutdown.sh
```

or whatever comes from `which sh`.

(I think I answer this question once a day)

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot for the effort. Unfortunately the computer(s) are not responding. Tried both /bin/sh and /usr/local/bin/bash (which runs the script). Manually works, cronjob not. As I mentioned before, a very similar script for the WOL runs perfectly with cronjob. 

Here's my cron log:

Apr  3 15:34:00 xxx/usr/sbin/cron[82636]: (root) CMD (   /usr/local/bin/bash /root/skriptid/WOL/test.sh  )

Apr  3 15:34:00 xxx /usr/sbin/cron[82636]: (root) CMD (   /usr/sh /root/skriptid/WOL/test.sh  )

Comment: Mmmm first of all we should see if `cron` is executed or not to see if it is cron or script error. I cannot get it from the script. Try a simple `* * * * * /bin/sh touch /tmp/file` and see if it works.

Comment: Hello! It seems that the touch did not do its job. I will try to sort out my /etc/cron and let know of the results :)

Comment: OK! Check also the possible configuration info in `/etc/cron.d` and `/etc/cron.d/allow, deny`.

Comment: Hey! I sorted out my two faulty lines in /etc/cron, and tested cron with simple touch and that thingy works. Altough... my script does not work. I even entered net rpc directly to cron, as follows: `8 17 * * * root net rpc SHUTDOWN -t 30 -f -C "Arvuti lulitub valja. Serveripoolne kask." -W xxx -U xxx\\xxx%xxx -S 192.168.2.102`
According to logs, crontab forwarded the command, but computer did not react. Given the same command directly to shell...it works like charm. Btw, freebsd does not have cron.d nor anything like it - simple /etc/crontab. Im really starting to think it's not meant to work.

Comment: What about trying `8 17 * * * root /path/to/net /path/to/rpc ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Add paths to your crontab

```
PATH=/etc:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable file sharing on windows computers in order for your script to work.